# Echo output for each value in given list in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

With below code I'm struggling to print calculation for each value in a given list. Currently it prints total combined time for both users, I want to echo individual time for each user which is listed in 2nd row of this code.\
Any help will be appreciated.

```
@Echo off
For %%U in (a3rgcw shukla) Do (

PushD "H:\Syslogs\" ||(Echo couldn't find dir & Pause & Exit /B 1)

Set "TotalSecs=0"

For %%F in ("*%U%*.txt") Do For /F "delims=" %%A in ('
    findstr /I "system.log.created End.of.session" "%%F"
') Do (
    Set "Flag="
    Echo=%%A|findstr /I "system.log.created" 2>&1>Nul && Set "Flag=Start"
    if defined Flag (
        FOR /F "tokens=11" %%T in ("%%A") Do Call :TimeToSecs Start "%%T"
    ) Else (
        FOR /F "tokens=8" %%T in ("%%A") Do Call :TimeToSecs Stop "%%T"
    )
)
Echo TotalDuration for %%U:%TotalDur%
)
Echo:
PopD
Goto :Eof

:TimeToSecs
Set "%1_HMS=%~2"
Echo:%~2|Findstr "[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" 2>&1>Nul || (Echo wrong format %2&Goto :Eof)
For /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%H in ("%~2"
) Do Set /A "%1=(1%%H-100)*60*60+(1%%I-100)*60+(1%%J-100)"
If %1 neq Stop Goto :Eof
Set /A "Diff=Stop-Start,TotalSecs+=Diff"
Call :Secs2HMS Dur %Diff%
Call :Secs2HMS TotalDur %TotalSecs%
::Echo Session from %Start_HMS% to %Stop_HMS% Duration:%Dur%      TotalDuration:%TotalDur%


Goto :Eof

:Secs2HMS var value
setlocal
set /a "HH=%2/3600,mm=(%2-HH*3600)/60+100,ss=%2 %% 60+100"
Set "HHmmss=   %HH%:%mm:~-2%:%ss:~-2%"
endlocal&set "%1=%HHmmss:~-10%
Goto :Eof
```

Current output:

```
TotalDuration for a3rgcw:   7:15:00
TotalDuration for shukla:   7:15:00
```

Desired output:

```
TotalDuration for a3rgcw:   5:15:00
TotalDuration for shukla:   2:00:00
```

Sample file named `shukladfdf` for 2nd user:

```
sdsdf system log created on  ghg Thursday, 9 August 2018, 20:30:45 on India 
Standard Time
dfg
drdwewed
end of session as 9 August 2018, 22:30:45 on India Standard Time
```

Comment: Thank you for including the current and desired output. Could you provide a small sample of input as well?

Comment: Please find sample data updated.

Comment: You are using %U% instead of %%U.

Comment: Add fix mention by Squashman. The line `Echo TotalDuration for %%U:%TotalDur%` can be changed to `Call Echo TotalDuration for %%U:%%TotalDur%%` to delay the expansion until execution time. Your sample outputs `TotalDuration for shukla:   2:00:00`. The sample does not reproduce the problem. Current `7:15:00` to desired `2:00:00` is unknown how to get that result from the sample.

Comment: @michael_heath, after making changes with fix mentioned by Squashman and you, working fine, you can post this as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Echo off
Setlocal

PushD "H:\Syslogs\" ||(Echo couldn't find dir & Pause & Exit /B 1)

For %%U in (a3rgcw shukla) Do (

    Set "TotalDur="
    Set "TotalSecs=0"

    For %%F in ("*%%U*.txt") Do For /F "delims=" %%A in ('
        findstr /I "system.log.created End.of.session" "%%F"
    ') Do (
        Set "FileName=%%F"
        Set "Flag="
        Echo=%%A|findstr /I "system.log.created" 2>&1>Nul && Set "Flag=Start"
        if defined Flag (
            FOR /F "tokens=11" %%T in ("%%A") Do Call :TimeToSecs Start "%%T"
        ) Else (
            FOR /F "tokens=8" %%T in ("%%A") Do Call :TimeToSecs Stop "%%T"
        )
    )

    Set "UsrName=%%U:          "
    Call :Print UsrName
)
Echo:
PopD
Goto :Eof

:Print
If /i "%~1" == "UsrName" (
    Echo TotalDuration for %UsrName:~,10% %TotalDur%
) else If /i "%~1" == "FileName" (
    Echo Session (%FileName%^) from %Start_HMS% to %Stop_HMS% Duration:%Dur%      TotalDuration:%TotalDur%
)
Goto :Eof

:TimeToSecs
Set "%1_HMS=%~2"
Echo:%~2|Findstr "[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" 2>&1>Nul || (Echo wrong format %2&Goto :Eof)
For /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%H in ("%~2"
) Do Set /A "%1=(1%%H-100)*60*60+(1%%I-100)*60+(1%%J-100)"
If %1 neq Stop Goto :Eof
Set /A "Diff=Stop-Start,TotalSecs+=Diff"
Call :Secs2HMS Dur %Diff%
Call :Secs2HMS TotalDur %TotalSecs%
Call :Print FileName
Goto :Eof

:Secs2HMS var value
setlocal
set /a "HH=%2/3600,mm=(%2-HH*3600)/60+100,ss=%2 %% 60+100"
Set "HHmmss=   %HH%:%mm:~-2%:%ss:~-2%"
endlocal&set "%1=%HHmmss:~-10%"
Goto :Eof
```

Changed `%U%` to `%%U`.

Changed `Echo TotalDuration for %%U:%TotalDur%` to
`Call Echo TotalDuration for %%U:%%TotalDur%%` which
delays expansion until time of execution, instead of
parse time.

Added missing double quote with 2nd last line to close.

Added `Setlocal` to top of script as perhaps a 2nd run
of the script in the same CMD session could set
predined variables with values.

Added label `:Print` to echo the output to avoid
use of delayed expansion.

Comment: I observed though file name doesn't have `user` defined names, still it prints value from previous result.

Comment: `a3rgcw` is found and process it with values. If `shukla` is not found, then it echoes result from `a3rgcw`. Fixed by undefining `TotalDur` at start of each loop.

Comment: Just 2 small changes needed (sorry to bother again). 1. I want `%TotalDur%` to be right aligned because `username` length would be varying. 2. I want to print file name also here: `::Echo Session (<filename>) from %Start_HMS% to`.

Comment: Modified the code some to to handle your request. **1**. `UsrName` trimmed at 10 characters to justify. Adjust the number and spaces if not correct with length. **2**. `FileName` Done.